# Problem when change IP of Virtual Machine then using PuTTY to connect

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine

I have an assignment to assign a new IP address to my VMware Ubuntu virtual machine and then deploy a WordPress site on it.

I used PuTTY to remotely connect from my Windows 10 host to the VM using ssh.
At first with the default config, I successfully deployed it.

However when I try to change the IP address of the VM by using UI I cannot connect through PuTTY anymore.

Is there anything I did wrong when I changed the IP address like that?

Answer (score -1):

First, you can use [openSSH instead of putty on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) nowoadays.
And you would then connect to it in command line with

```
ssh user@<serverName / IP address>
```

But, if you are using an IP address instead of a server name, then yes, changing said IP would change your URL (and your Putty configuration)